# Looking for proof of a second derivative identity

Tags: derivatives

I'm pretty sure this is true, but haven't been able to figure out or find a proof, largely because I haven't been able to figure out what to Google for.

$$
\frac{d^2x}{dy^2} (\frac{dy}{dx})^2+ \frac{dx}{dy} \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0
$$

I would appreciate some help, even if it just a link to somewhere this is proven. (Or if it is not true, maybe a counterexample?)

Comment: Are we assuming $y = f(x)$ or $x = g(y)$ for some function $f$ or $g$, or working with some other function $h(x, y)$?

Answer (score 1):

The relation is correct, provided that all is well interpreted. Unfortunately your notation may create confusion, and so let me suggest a more pedantic approach.

Let $y=f(x)$. Then $x=g(y)$, where $g$ is the inverse of $f$ (let's assume that it exists on a particular region). Then $1=g'(y)f'(x)$, in view of the chain rule, and so also
$$
0=g''(y)f'(x)+(g'(y))^2f''(x).
$$
Hence,
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{d^2x}{dy^2} \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+ \frac{dx}{dy} \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}
&=g''(y)(f'(x))^2+g'(y)f''(x)\\
&=-(g'(y))^2f''(x)f'(x)+g'(y)f''(x)\\
&=-g'(y)f''(x)+g'(y)f''(x)=0.
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. It is obtained by differentiating the following on both sides:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy}=1
$$